# Bind 9 on multiple networks

Tags: networking, dns, bind, domain-server

Hi guys i need your help, i have my domain and i have multiple networks.

i have 192.168.1.0/24 - workstations, servers, dhcp, dns, sip phones, 
       192.168.3.0/24 - from another location- wks, dhcp, dns, sip phones..
       192.168.20.0/24 -  Network for wifi ubiquit APs and TVs, and adroid
       192.168.21.0/24 - VMs -  dns, db, www, ha, file , mail
       192.168.22.0/24 - VMs -  dns, db, www, ha, file, mail

Now i have bind on all these networks,env and i want host, workstations, sip phones to call each other by host name. All of these device have hostname and IP. Right now its only working in 192.168.1.0/24 devices can call each other by host as i have ddns on dhcp.

I have one domain - mydomain.com. So for this setup its only for local resolution not outside my LANs NO just internal resolution. So i have

mydomain.local - 192.168.1.0/24
mydomain.local - 192.168.3.0/24
mydomain.test - 192.168.21.0/24 & 192.168.22.0/24 ( test env)
mydomain.stage - 192.168.21.0/24 & 192.168.22.0/24 (stage env)

All these IPs can ping each other its working but now by hostname is what i want

so i want host in mydomain.local to ping mydomain.test, mydomain.stage and vise vesa.

Please help